# trying to merge chunks to trigger better balancing after 50% of the data was deleted by the developers

Tags: mongodb

Trying to merge chunks using the following command:

```
         db.adminCommand
         ( {
           mergeChunks: "HTMLDumps.HTMLRepository",
           bounds: [ {   "ShardMapId" : 2, "DomainId" : 62 },
           {  "ShardMapId" : 2, "DomainId" : 162 } ]
         } )
```

getting the following error when trying to run the above command to try to merge any of the available consecutive chunks available on a shard:

```
             {
             "ok" : 0,
             "errmsg" : "Failed to commit chunk merge :: caused by :: 
             DuplicateKey: chunk operation commit failed: version 
             32|6||5ba8d864bba4ff264edf0bd9 doesn't exist in 
             namespace: HTMLDumps.HTMLRepository. Unable to save 
             chunk ops. Command: { applyOps: [ { op: \"u\", b: false, 
             ns: \"config.chunks\", o: { _id: \"HTM 
             Dumps.HTMLRepository-ShardMapId_2.0DomainId_62.0\", ns: 
             \"HTMLDumps.HTMLRepository\", min: { ShardMapId: 2.0, 
             DomainId: 62.0 }, max: { ShardMapId: 2, DomainId: 162 }, 
             shard: \"shard0000\", lastmod: Timestamp(32, 6), 
             lastmodEpoch: ObjectId('5ba8d864bba4ff264edf0bd9') }, 
             o2: { _id: \"HTMLDumps.HTMLRepository- 
             ShardMapId_2.0DomainId_62.0\" } }, { op: \"d\", ns: 
             \"config.chunks\", o: { _id: \"HTMLDumps.HTMLRepository- 
             ShardMapId_2DomainId_109\" } } ], preCondition: [ { ns: 
             \"config.chunks\", q: { query: { ns: 
             \"HTMLDumps.HTMLRepository\", min: { ShardMapId: 2.0, 
             DomainId: 62.0 }, max: { ShardMapId: 2, DomainId: 109 } 
             }, orderby: { lastmod: -1 } }, res: { lastmodEpoch: 
             ObjectId('5ba8d864bba4ff264edf0bd9'), shard: 
             \"shard0000\" } }, { ns: \"config.chunks\", q: { query: 
             { ns: \"HTMLDumps.HTMLRepository\", min: { ShardMapId: 
             2, DomainId: 109 }, max: { ShardMapId: 2, DomainId: 162 
             } }, orderby: { lastmod: -1 } }, res: { lastmodEpoch: 
             ObjectId('5ba8d864bba4ff264edf0bd9'), shard: 
             \"shard0000\" } } ], writeConcern: { w: 0, wtimeout: 0 } 
             }. Result: { applied: 1, code: 11000, codeName: 
             \"DuplicateKey\", errmsg: \"E11000 duplicate key error 
             collection: config.chunks index: ns_1_min_1 dup key: { : 
             \"HTMLDumps.HTMLRepository\", : { ShardMapId: 2.0, 
             DomainId: 62.0 } }\", results: [ false ], ok: 0.0, 
             operationTime: Timestamp(1554112692, 1), $gleStats: { 
             lastOpTime: { ts: Timestamp(1554112692, 1), t: 13 },  
             electionId: ObjectId('7fffffff000000000000000d') }, 
             $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1554112692, 1), 
             signature: { hash: BinData(0, 
             0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), keyId: 0 } } 
             } :: caused by :: E11000 duplicate key error collection: 
             config.chunks index: ns_1_min_1 dup key: { : 
             \"HTMLDumps.HTMLRepository\", : { ShardMapId: 2.0, 
             DomainId: 62.0 } }",
             "code" : 11000,
             "codeName" : "DuplicateKey",
             "operationTime" : Timestamp(1554112687, 1),
             "$clusterTime" : {
             "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1554112687, 1),
             "signature" : {
                "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
               }
              }
             }
```

This is happening regardless of which chunks i select. Main reason for me to try to do this is to achieve true data balancing and not just chunk numbers. Recently developers deleted 90% of the data from these chunks that caused the distribution to get to 90% 10% state from 60/40 earlier. I hope to merge/remove empty chunks to ensure balancing of the data to reach as close to 60/40 as possible.

Comment: Please provide sh.status() result.

Comment: --- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
        "currentVersion" : 6,
        "clusterId" : ObjectId("5b86b47af9a7b76e45807b94")
  }
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "192.168.8.24:27017",  "state" : 1,  "tags" : [ ] }
        {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "192.168.8.25:27017",  "state" : 1,  "tags" : [ ] }
  active mongoses:
        "3.6.7" : 1
  autosplit:
        Currently enabled: yes

Comment: balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  5
        Last reported error:  Connection refused
        Time of Reported error:  Sun Mar 24 2019 11:56:43 GMT+0530 (IST)
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours:
                No recent migrations

Comment: databases:
        {  "_id" : "HTMLDumps",  "primary" : "shard0001",  "partitioned" : true }
                HTMLDumps.HTMLRepository
                        shard key: { "ShardMapId" : 1, "DomainId" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                shard0000       59
                                shard0001       61
                        too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print

Comment: {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
                config.system.sessions
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                shard0000       1
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 0)

Comment: { "ShardMapId" : 1, "DomainId" : 344 } -->> { "ShardMapId" : 2, "DomainId" : 62 } on : shard0000 Timestamp(28, 8)
                        { "ShardMapId" : 2, "DomainId" : 62 } -->> { "ShardMapId" : 2, "DomainId" : 109 } on : shard0000 Timestamp(28, 9)
                        { "ShardMapId" : 2, "DomainId" : 109 } -->> { "ShardMapId" : 2, "DomainId" : 162 } on : shard0000 Timestamp(28, 10)

Comment: last comment is the sample detailed chunk sizes that i was trying to merge. cannot share complete as its too big

Comment: @AmardeepSingh, What is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: MongoDB shell version v3.6.7

Comment: db version v3.6.7

Comment: Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Please check https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/SERVER/issues/SERVER-40061?filter=allissues. There is already an open issue with a similar kind of problem, where MongoDB is working as well.

Comment: thank you, i understand its an open bug. I will track the shared link for further updates.

Comment: One additional query: Is there any other way for me to clean up the empty chunks so to correct the data distribution back to 60-40 range instead of 90-10 it is now, since the bulk deletion was done.

Comment: Can i use this url: "https://medium.com/@dash1e/mongodb-merge-all-empty-chunks-6e367680f78d"